# ColdFusion HTML Form breaking on quotes

Tags: forms, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Oddly I have a form that will not pass a double quote?

For Example:

`10 and single ' this" And " Another`

In the Input form stops at:
`10 and single ' this`

Why is it not preserving the double quote? "

I do have the form type as: `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

I have other forms that are just fine with quotes.

Comment: Where is it not preserving double quotes? When you are trying to save in the database or when you try to display the for with prefilled data in input?

Comment: In the form input.  I can put 10" Pipe in form and submit. It goes through fine.  When I go to edit that same entry to say maybe 10" PVC Pipe.  It only shows the 10 in the form input.  Not 10" Pipe

Comment: The double quote is breaking your html for `<input>`. You might want to use `value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(Value)#"`.

Comment: Initially the input `value=""` so there is no issue. When editing, the field value populated with a string containing a double quote, which the browser interprets as the end of the value,  so `value="10" PVC Pipe"` is truncated after "10"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is that the double quote mark in the text `10 and single ' this" And " Another` is breaking the input element.

The text with `"` will  prematurely end the `value` attribute.

eg `<input value="10 and single ' this" And " Another">`

To get over this, you'll need to user

```
<input value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(formValue)#">
```

Comment: Yes worked.  What I found odd was this has not done this on other forms. hmmm

Comment: IHMO, this should be done on all form fields. Also `encodeForHTMLAttribute()` can be useful in `<option value="#encodeForHTMLAttribute(data)#">`

Comment: Merle, If the quotes in the value field are mismatched that way, the field value will always be truncated